Logback creating .tmp files during rollover
I have spring boot app with springboot version - 2.7.18 which has logback version 1.2.12
Now I am facing issue with .tmp files getting created during daily rollover of files.
Below is my logback.xml code:
<springProfile name="local, dev, stg, prod"> 

<springProperty name="ENV" source="spring-profiles.active">
<springProperty name="LOGGING_FILE_PATH" source="logging.file.path">
<springProperty name="LOGGING_FILE_NAME" source="logging.file.name"/>
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic sift.SiftingAppender">
<discriminator><Key>LOGGING_FILE_NAME</key> <defaultValue>ProcessingApp</defaultValue>
</discriminator>
<sift>
<appender name="FILE-${LOGGING_FILE_NAME}_${ENV}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${LOGGING_FILE_PATH}/${LOGGING_FILE_NAME}_${ENV}.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>${LOGGING_FILE_PATH}/${LOGGING_FILE_NAME}_$(ENV}-%d{VYYY-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern><maxHistory>180</maxHistory></rollingPolicy>
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
<Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
</sift>
</appender>
<root level=“info”>
<appender-ref ref=“SIFT”>
</root>
</springProfile>

Additional Info - I have multiple jobs invoking endpoint in application & for each job it creates a separate log file.
Appreciate any help or suggestions on to resolve issue.
